# Quais são as diferenças entre <MERGE> e <INCLUDE>?

Tags: android, xml

Costumo trabalhar com INCLUDE, mas nunca entendi o MERGE. Quais são seus usos e vantagens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include e Merge são coisas distintas mas que foram feitas para serem utilizadas juntas.

Include é utilizado para reaproveitar layouts, simples assim. Mas isso gera um problema, pois todo layout definido em Android precisa iniciar com um tag pai (uma ViewGroup) que vai conter todos os elementos do seu layout.

Se você simplesmente utilizar um layout dentro do outro (com include), pode acabar tendo um pai dentro de outro pai, por exemplo uma LinearLayout dentro de outra LinearLayout. Isso é muito ruim para a estrutura hierarquica de views no Android. É ai que a tag merge pode te ajudar.

A única maneira de você criar um layout reutilizável, sem que você tenha que especificar uma tag pai (uma ViewGroup como por exemplo o LinearLayout) é utilizando a tag merge. Que vai ser desconsiderada quando o sistema juntar os dois layouts.

Neste examplo, a tag merge substitui a utilização de uma ViewGroup (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, FrameLayout, etc) para conter dois botões.

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/delete"/>

</merge>
```

Com este layout, quando você utilizar a tag include para utilizá-lo, o sistema vai colocar 2 botões diretamente no layout de destino ignorando a tag merge.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Pra quem não tiver entendido, segue o link da documentação, http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html.